# Checking if Nokogiri object is nil before accessing text method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to search through XML that I received from an API.

```
fiber = doc.xpath("/*[name()='food']/*[name()='servings']/*
 [name()='serving']/*[name()='fiber']").first.text
```

Sometimes though, the child element (e.g. fiber) is missing from the response. In this case, Nokogiri returns a nil object and my code throws the appropriate exception (undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass) because I'm trying to access the 'text' method of a nil object.

What's a clean and fast way to check if the child element (e.g. fiber) exists before actually trying to call the 'text' method on it? If it doesn't exist, I'd like to set the value to 0. I'm also doing this for several other child elements (e.g. calories, carbohydrates, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "try" for those cases

```
fiber = doc.xpath("/*[name()='food']/*[name()='servings']/*
     [name()='serving']/*[name()='fiber']").first.try(:text)
```

It returns nil if first is nil, and it calles text if it's not nil

If you need a default value in case it's nil you can do

```
fiber = doc.xpath("/*[name()='food']/*[name()='servings']/*
     [name()='serving']/*[name()='fiber']").first.try(:text) or 'default'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. It turned out I didn't need to use the 'default' option because 'nil + x = x', and that's the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = doc.xpath("/*[name()='food']/*[name()='servings']/*
```

[name()='serving']/*[name()='fiber']")

```
fiber = element.present? ? element.first.text : <handle other case here>
```